# Вставить картинку в QtTableWidget на весь размер ячейки

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Нужно вставить картинку в QtTableWidget на весь размер ячейки .

Comment: Вот вам кусочки пазла: [QTableWidget::setItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem), [QTableWidgetItem::setData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData), [Qt::DecorationRole](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). Попробуйте собрать их вместе